# Is there a way to view how much memory a SciPy matrix used?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I know in python it's hard to see the memory usage of an object.

Is it easier to do this for SciPy objects (for example, sparse matrix)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use array.itemsize (size of the contained type in bytes) and array.flat to obtain the lenght:

```
# a is your array
bytes = a.itemsize * a.size
```

it's not the exact value, as it ignore the whole array infrastructure, but for big array it's the value that matter (and I guess that you care because you have something big)

if you want to use it on a sparse array you have to modify it, as the sparse doesn't have the itemsize attribute. You have to access the dtype and get the itemsize from it:

```
bytes = a.dtype.itemsize * a.size
```

In general I don't think it's easy to evaluate the real memory occupied by a python object...the numpy array is an exception being just a thin layer over a C array

Comment: you are completly right, I just forgot about the size attribute

Comment: if you are not sure of which kind of object you will have in your hand it's better to use the second version, as it works even for standard arrays

Comment: It should work for a sparse matrix, however it will ignore the metadata necessary (typically the arrays `sparse.indptr` and `sparse.indices`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside IPython, you can also use its `%whos`[magic function](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.namespace.html), which gives you information about the session's variables and includes how much RAM each takes.